# SignalR core not working with cookie Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I cant seem to get SignalR core to work with cookie authentication. I have set up a test project that can successfully authenticate and make subsequent calls to a controller that requires authorization. So the regular authentication seems to be working.

But afterwards, when I try and connect to a hub and then trigger methods on the hub marked with `Authorize` the call will fail with this message: `Authorization failed for user: (null)`

I inserted a dummy middleware to inspect the requests as they come in. When calling `connection.StartAsync()` from my client (xamarin mobile app), I receive an `OPTIONS` request with `context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` being equal to true. Directly after that `OnConnectedAsync` on my hub gets called. At this point `_contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false. What is responsible to de-authenticating my request. From the time it leaves my middleware, to the time OnConnectedAsync is called, something removes the authentication.

Any Ideas?

Sample Code:

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        await this._next(context);

        //At this point context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true
    }
}

public class TestHub: Hub
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public TestHub(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        //At this point _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false

        await Task.FromResult(1);
    }

    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", message);
    }

    [Authorize]
    public Task SendAuth(string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("SendAuth", message + " Authed");
    }
}


public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyDataBase1"));
        services.AddIdentity<Auth, MyRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => {

            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

        });

        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddTransient<TestHub>();
        services.AddTransient<MyMiddleware>();

        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<TestHub>("TestHub");
        }); 

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=App}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the client code:

```
public async Task Test()
{
    var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        CookieContainer = cookieJar,
        UseCookies = true,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false
    };


    var client = new HttpClient(handler);

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((new Auth { Name = "craig", Password = "12345" }));

    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var result1 = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/My", content); //cookie created

    var result2 = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/My/authtest", content); //cookie tested and works


    var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl("http://localhost:5000/TestHub")
        .WithConsoleLogger()
        .WithMessageHandler(handler)
        .Build();



    connection.On<string>("Send", data =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received: {data}");
    });

    connection.On<string>("SendAuth", data =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received: {data}");
    });

    await connection.StartAsync();

    await connection.InvokeAsync("Send", "Hello"); //Succeeds, no auth required

    await connection.InvokeAsync("SendAuth", "Hello NEEDSAUTH"); //Fails, auth required

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue in the WebSocketsTransport where we don't copy Cookies into the websocket options. We currently copy headers only. I'll file an issue to get it looked at.

Comment: Hey Brennan, I assume this is on the client side? I tried overriding SendAsync on a HttpClientHandler and adding a cookie to each request. But it seems that this also does not work. Do you have a suggestion of how I can set a header that will be copied over? I just need to be able to auth. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yeah this is on the client. If you're using the alpha2 release then it might not be possible to use headers for WebSockets, although you can always use a query string. If you are on newer dev bits then you can use the `.WithHeader` extension on `HubConnectionBuilder`

Comment: Sweet, thanks dude, Will check out the dev branch for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Core 2 try changing the order of UseAuthentication, place it before the UseSignalR method.

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseSignalR...
```

Then inside the hub the Identity property shouldn't be null.

```
Context.User.Identity.Name
```